# No texture on mesh after import from mesh lab

Tags: import

After importing my cleaned up mesh from mesh Lab I have a solid color on it.
Does anyone know why this happened?
Thanks

Comment: You didn't mention the format you imported as, but regardless of that, practically any format you import will have only generic materials. You must recreate your own materials inside of blender after importing.

Comment: Depends how you cleaned up the mesh in MeshLab. There are some approaches that require extra steps to get the texture for the modified mesh.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, very helpful.